# Перезапись данных в txt файле

Tags: python-2.7, arcgis

Имеется txt файл с вот такой строкой:
`NUMBER  COD STAT COMP EDIT`
пытаюсь перезаписать эти данные на `Обязательные поля заполнены` но  при попытке получается вот это `Обязательные поля заполненыUMBER STAT`те часть старых данных остаётся. Файл открывается в режиме w+ так же использую `seek(0)`
какие есть способы чтобы полностью можно было убрать старые данные и записать новые в одном и том же файле

```
with open(r'{}\{}.txt'.format(Outfile,fcc[-1]), 'w+') as f:
      for field in fields:
        cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc,fields)
        for d in df["Name"].unique():
              if field.name in d:
                f.write ('{}'.format(field.name)+'\n')
                for row in cursor:
                  if row.getValue(field.name)== "":
                    f.write ('{}'.format(row.getValue(field_1))+'\n')
                    a.add(row.getValue(field_1))
      else:
        if len(a)== 0:
          f.seek(0)
          f.write ('Обязательные поля заполнены')
```

Comment: Файл при точечной перезаписи поверх останется такого же размера. Вы можете только если пробелы поверх имеющегося текста записать, чтобы затереть символы. Сам файл автоматически не "ужимается" в пустоты, чтобы поменять размер файла его нужно заново записать.

Answer (score 0):

Помогло использование `f.truncate(0)` - усечение размера файла, соответственно и всего что содержится в файле

Comment: Тогда не проще ли было в режиме `'w'` файл открыть, да переписать целиком? )

Comment: @CrazyElf попробую и такой вариант